# How to integrate Web Game into Android

Tags: android, web, 2d-games

Basically i have created a application in php. and now I want to know in which platform i should make game which will integrate on web as well as android .

I was going for unity3d but unity3d has a problem of plugin on different browser which will not be a better option .

I want to build a game like tetris with different senerio

Comment: Your question is too Generic. I suggest you be more specific to issues and share your research

Comment: You may need to look at http://phpforandroid.net/ but you may not be able to utilize front end code (if you have a lot). In that case http://www.appcelerator.com/ or phone gap http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_index.md.html may be a good option.

Comment: i know i can create a service in json which can transform into phonegap and used for android . but what i am actually trying to say i want create a game like tetris which can be used for android as well as web at the same time.